# google captcha: Captcha Field is not rendered after reset

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I'm using the google captcha as described at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render.
I have a form which is being sent over ajax.After click my "Send" button I send my request.
If the form has an error, the form is new loaded and I also want that the captcha is new loaded. But when I make a `grecaptcha.reset();` the captcha field is not shown anymore.

I already tried, to create the capture field with

```
grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
        'sitekey' : 'MYKEY'
    });
```

and then, after reload the form with this capture in it, I made

```
var captchawidget = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
                'sitekey' : 'MYKEY'
            });

            grecaptcha.reset(captchawidget);
```

Then the capture is loaded, but after clicking again on my send button, there is the an error:

```
TypeError: ge(...) is null

...valid ReCAPTCHA client id: "+a);return ge(Yp(b.id)).value},$p=function(){return!...
```

Can anyone help me with this? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a widget id to render again

```
var widgetId = grecaptcha.render(container);
grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
```